# Using Classes to operate on Data Frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, class, time-series

In my project using Classes makes a lot of sense:

- The class will contain time-series data which will be repetitively used.
- It will have methods/functions operating on those time series and called many times

Problem is that I want to use pandas Data Frames as time series container (*in some instance, it will be a one-time Series - Panda's Series, in others multiple time series - Panda's DataFrame*)  and I have issues with returning and operating on Padas DataFrames withing Class.

I've done reading around this topic, but I couldn't find an elegant and simple solution. Can you please help?

I've prepared a simplified example of DataFrame operations on time-series withing Class.

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, my_dataframe, time_series_type):
        self.my_dataframe = my_dataframe
        self.time_series_type = time_series_type

def returns(self):
    r = self.my_dataframe.pct_change()
    r = r.fillna(0, inplace = True)
    return r #returns Panda's DataFrame

def rebase_to_1(self):
    rebase_to_1 = self.returns + 1
    rebase_to_1 = rebase_to_1.cumprod()
    return rebase_to_1 #returns Panda's DataFrame
```

Example of application:

```
a = MyClass(my_time_series1)
b = MyClass(my_time_series2)

#Show rebased time-series/PadasDataFrame in Jupiter notebook
a.rebase_to_1()
```

I have quite a lot of functions which I'm trying to put inside the class to streamline operating on time-series. I hope that example above illustrates this well enough.

Comment: shouldnt you call `a.rebase_to_1()` ?

Comment: Thanks, my typo.